# How to create my own field in many2one?

Tags: python, xml, odoo

In openerp I have created many to one field. It has number of customer of my form

xml

```
<field name = "customer_name" on_change="on_change_customer(customer_name)"/>
```

python

```
'customer_name': fields.many2one('res.partner','customer name'),
```

The above code is working fine. It is showing customer name.

But I want to list out the client id. So that I'm coding like follow

xml

```
<field name= "client_id" domain="[('client_id','=',True)]" on_change="on_change_customer(client_id)"/>
```

python

```
'client_id': fields.many2one('res.partner','Client Id'),
```

When using this code it is not showing id. It just show only "create and edit"

I want to show client id. What is the problem of my code?

Answer (score 0):

add :

```
_rec_name="Your Fields"
```

After _desciption

may be you will get your answer